# Angular: Reinitialize reactive form material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-form-field

I've a problem with a form with one input from material library.
[image: input]

When I submit the form, I reset it like this in my submission method :

```
onSubmitPriceForm() {
      // to do......
      this.priceForm.reset();
    }
```

}

the problem is that the form appears like this just after validation :
[image: input in warning]

I would like the field to return to the original state as in Photo 1

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Edit here's validors :

```
initPriceForm() {
    this.priceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      price: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pricePattern)]]
    });
  }
```

new edit : here's the form html :

```
<form [formGroup]="priceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitPriceForm()">
            <div class="edit-price-form">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" errorState="false">
                    <mat-label>{{ 'PRIX_TTC.NOUVEAU_PRIX_TTC' | translate }}</mat-label>
                    <input matInput name="price" autocomplete="off" formControlName="price" required>
                </mat-form-field>
    
                <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary">
                    <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: It's hard to say  without seeing your implementation of validators, but usually you need to mark your FormGroup / FormControls as untouched and / or pristine i.e. `this.priceForm.markAsPristine(); this.priceForm.markAsUntouched();`

Comment: I added the validators, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> By default, these error messages are shown when the control is invalid
> and either the user has interacted with (touched) the element or the
> parent form has been submitted

You can change this behaviour by using customError matcher

**component.ts**

```
export class InputOverviewExample {
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  group = new FormGroup({
    control:new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })
}

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    // const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="group" class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" formControlName="control">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button (click)="group.get('control')!.reset();"> Click</button>
  
</form>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3hdad?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work. I had already tried

Comment: If that is not working then you can set custom error matcher to mat-input something like this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3hdad?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html